# Show Diff of two trees in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, treeview, diff

In Eclipse, I am using a TreeViewer to show a custom tree, whose contents are drawn from an ITreeContentProvider. Now I am trying to create a second view that allows me to automatically show a two-way comparisons of two such trees. I found various views for textual comparison within Eclipse, but I could not find an easy way to show the structural differences between two arbitrary trees. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When the Data Model the ContentProvider is creating and the labelProvider is diplaying is the Same, you could use the same viewer in the right and the left of a view.

You could than compare the TreeItem Elements of both TreeViewer and mark the ones, which has changed.

The other solution is to compare the DataModels and add a special flag to the changed elements. The LabelProvider can check this flag and draw a special color to indicate, that this element is different.

I do not know an Editor inside Eclipse, providing this functionality.